# JUnit and Maven build fails in eclipse with java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: address?

Tags: java, maven-2, junit4

When I try and run either JUnit (4.8.2) tests or a maven (2.2.1) build in my local eclipse I get the following error:

```
JUnit 4.8.2
    java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: address
        at java.net.InetAddress.init(Native Method)
        at java.net.InetAddress.<clinit>(InetAddress.java:242)
        at java.net.InetSocketAddress.<init>(InetSocketAddress.java:200)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:189)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.connect(RemoteTestRunner.java:570)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:381)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)

Maven 2.2.1
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: address
    at java.net.InetAddress.init(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress.<clinit>(InetAddress.java:242)
    at java.net.InetSocketAddress.<init>(InetSocketAddress.java:200)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:163)
        etc...
```

Judging from a few posts people say this might be conflicting dependencies but I'm not sure.  Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT:
Running `mvn clean install` from the command line works but eclipse won't let me do a maven build, clean, or run any of my test because of this error, any ideas what I need to do?

Cheers,

Alexei Blue

Comment: Surely a conflicting dependency wouldn't affect both in the same way?  Have you just tried cleaning the project in Eclipse?  What happens when you run maven on the command line?

Comment: Running a clean install on the command line with maven built the project successfully but still in eclipse the tests and maven builds produce the same error as above, very strange.

Comment: That's okay, command line build is the important one.  Usually a project refresh plus clean and rebuild solves stuff like this.  Otherwise you can update the maven project from within Eclipse.

Comment: When I run the maven clean from inside eclipse I get the following: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.4.1: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.4.1 from/to central: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: address -> [Help 1]  Might be my plugin in eclipse, I'll try update it...  FYI it works fine for other projects in eclipse

Comment: In M2e you can right click a project goto to 'Maven', select 'Update Project' and check 'Force update of snapshots'.  I would expect any other plugin to have an identical function.

Comment: Yeah thats what I've been doing so far, it seems to update the snapshots okay, but for some reason when I do a maven clean it expects maven-clean-plugin/2.2 so it tries to download it which is what causes this error...  hmmmm I might have to manually download it and see if it runs offline, I still can't see why it can find the field Address though

Comment: Still no idea why it won't build in eclipse, I can't run any of my unit tests because of this error but in other projects they run fine, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it was a corrupt JDK.  I pointed it to another version of Java 6 and it worked fine so not sure how it got corrupt but it appears the field Address has gone missing.

Comment: I was having exactly the same problem with Oracle's Java 1.6.0_45. After switching in the run configuration to 1.7.0_21 the tests started running again.